# Javascript RegEx Exactly one Digit Pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, match, digit

```
str = "33d4m"; //d for days and h for hours and m for min
patt=/^[1-9]+d/i;
result=patt.test(str);
document.write("Returned value: " +  result);
```

I want result return true if and only if there is one digit before d, i.e;less than 10days remaining or a few hours remaining like i want return true also on

```
str = "23h5m"
```

if two digit before d then return false
if two digit before h then return true.
Where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
patt=/^\d{1,2}h|^\dd/i
```

It means:

> ```
>    Match 1 or 2 digits followed by the literal 'h' 
> OR match a single digit followed by the literal 'd'
> ```

Comment: Thanks, Outstanding approach.

Comment: @Wasim Thanks, i just re-edited it, i changed the `[1-9]` character sets to `\d` digits because otherwise `20h5M` wouldn't match.

Comment: i do understand that, i understand regex but can't creat it due to lack of practice with regex. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

i think something like this would work:

```
patt=/^[1-9][dh]/i
```

Comment: can you put some sample cases. how much is "a few hours?"

Comment: hours obviously will not be greater than 23

Comment: patt=/^[1-9]d|h/i is working for me, but i think it should not work. Why its working. it should return false on str = "23h" but it true, WHY?

Comment: str = "10d 10h 7m"; here what pattern should return false because days are greater than or equal to 10

Answer (score 1):

The plus means "at least one" - remove it.  You may also want to use `[0-9]` for *all* digits, but that is just a guess.

```
patt=/^[1-9]d/i;
```

Comment: correct, if str = "23h34M" then it should also return true. is that possible

Comment: this comment makes no sense, there is no correlation between it return false for 33d4M but true for 23h34M. to have a regex work you need a pattern...what's the pattern?

Comment: pattern is [1-9]d or [1-9][1-9]h , basically d for days and h for hours. i need return true if days are less than 10 or few hours left